# How to connect a 2 pin photodiode?

Tags: sensor, photodiode, light-sensor

Initially, I have used 3 pin photodiodes, where the anode is connected to the resistor and has a wire which goes to group and the other goes to an analogue input to read the voltage. The cathode is connected to the power supply and the case is also connected to the ground.

3 PIN Photodiode - https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/313/AD500-8_TO_500030_500305_500155-586522.pdf

Now I am using a 2 pin photodiode which only has a cathode and a case pin. [image: Image of Cathode and Case Pin]

How does this get connected? Do I still run the power to the cathode and then where do I get the voltage output from the photodiodes?

2 PIN Photodiode - https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/720-BPX61

Thanks

Comment: What sensitivity, (lux range) and slew rate (V/us or V/s) are you looking for?  Do you want to use an Op Amp?  Single supply?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode

Answer (score 0):

For your 2-pin device, the anode will be connected to the case.

If this isn't acceptable for your application (for example, the case will be in contact with some grounded object, but you don't want the anode grounded), then you'll need to find a different device to use.

Comment: in the drawing the cathode seems to be welded to the case